# MongoDB in Azure Cloud

Tags: mongodb, azure

Is it possible to run more than one instance of MongoDB in Azure? I need (in the future) partition database to many node.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Do you want multiple azure instances running mongod that one mongos can talk to?

Comment: I want run many mongo nodes to create shards(scaling out database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run multiple instances if you use a replica set, as you can then use internal endpoints for inter-node communication. If you only have standalone instances, they won't be able to communicate with each other and won't share data.

I've been presenting this at various Mongodb conferences (DC, Silicon Valley), and you can watch the Silicon Valley video recording of my presentation [here](http://www.10gen.com/video/mongosv2010/azure).

EDIT: 10gen has now published a .NET project that launches a replicaset, improving upon the original work I did, and may be downloaded [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure/), with docs [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure).

Comment: One more thing: they way I have it running today, I use the mongos router to allow the outside world to communicate with the replica set, with a single-shard configuration (basically the entire db in one shard). It's possible to configure shards as well (with each shard being a replica set), but I don't have a working sample for that yet.